# .NET 5 WPF EntityFramework with SQL Compact Edition

Tags: .net-core, sql-server-ce, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5

Is there a way to use EF with SQL Compact database on the new .NET 5 Windows Framework?
I tried it, but I couldn't make it workable.

Is this library supported in .NET 5?
EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 (looks empty the package folder)

I cannot access to the optionsBuilder.UseSqlCe(@"Data Source=C:\data\Blogging.sdf"); method.

If it is not supported, can I use EF with CE in .NET Core 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library only supports EF Core 2.2.
If I get a sponsor I am willing to update.

You can use SQLCE with raw ADO.NET and .NET 5.

See more info here; https://erikej.github.io/sqlce/2020/08/17/netcore-sql-compact.html

Comment: And .NET 5 with EF 6.4.4 support EF CE?

Comment: No, that is not supported

Comment: So this link is just for EF Core 2.2?: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/wiki/Using-EF-Core-with-SQL-Server-Compact-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications

Comment: But if i look this table (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/), it says EF 6.4 support SQL CE...

Comment: Is this package never will be upgrade to .NET 5 architecture? (do you mean in your answer, when you write if you get sponsored...?) https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/6.4.4

Comment: The EF6 package only works with .NET Framework